# Tax display is wrong

Tags: magento2, price, tax, category-products

I am going crazy slowly as I cannot solve this. Maybe anyone here can help me out.

Problem 1: My shop always shows 2 prices (incl. & excl. tax) on category page but settings are clearly only including tax.

Problem 2: The tax does not get added on product page product

So, I have set everything in my backend as "Including tax".

My tax settings are:

[image: Tax settings]

1. Problem: On my category product page, all products always show with and without tax (with tax is a link)

--> Does anyone know, how I can only show one price here and not have both incl. and excl. displayed

[image: 2 prices display]

2. Problem: The price on product page is shown always without tax

--> Does anyone have an idea why as my settings usually say differently

[image]

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Best regards

Comment: have you already cleared your cache/reindex your site?

Comment: Hello, yes I have. Now I have checked the display on category page and it shows some strange <span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee">
            <span class="price-label">As low as</span>
        <span id="194" data-price-amount="18.456901" data-price-type="" class="price-wrapper ">€18.46</span>
        </span> Wee tax. But my Fixed product tax is disabled :/

Comment: may be you set configuration with store view.